# Avoiding intersections with QGIS Spline plugin (Version 2.0)

Tags: qgis

Has anyone gotten the QGIS 'avoid intersections' option to work when adding polygons via the Spline plugin? When checking the option and enable topological editing, I continue getting overlaps in my polygons when adding using the spline tool. When adding polygons using the regular add polygon tool, the intersections are successfully avoided and no overlap occurs with new polygons.